# How can I use prime factorization to find a cube root?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, factoring

This is based on a [lesson at Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/arithmetic/exponents-radicals/radical-radicals/v/finding-cube-roots) that I didn't understand.

In the lesson, the instructor uses the number 512 as an example and the entire prime factorization consists of three groups of three 2s.  However, not every number has such a nice prime factorization and I don't understand how to use prime factorization to determine a cube root.

For example, if the number is 1000, I know the cube root is 10, but how do I get there using prime factorization.

The prime factorization of 1000 is 2 * 2 * 2 * 5 * 5 * 5.  Since it's six prime numbers, I can't get 3 equal groups of the same number like I could with 512.  In another forum someone said to use three groups of the smallest factor, but three 2s doesn't get me 10.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing a copy of $2$. $1000 = 2^{3}5^{3}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a **third** factor of $2$ in your prime factorization of $1000$:

$$1000 = 2\cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 \cdot 5 = (2^3\cdot 5^3) = (2\cdot 5)^3 = (2\times 5) \cdot (2\times 5) \cdot (2 \times 5) = 10 ^3$$

Comment: Can you see how to reorder the terms, to get three groups/factors of $10$?

Comment: We simply rearrange the *order* of the factors (which doesn't change their product): $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 5\cdot 5 = 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 5 = 10 \cdot 10 \cdot 10$

Comment: I think I get it.  I was thinking I had to use the numbers *in order*.  I forgot that the order is arbitrary.  DOH!  So, my three groups are all 2*5.  Now that I realize this, I think I can apply it to other numbers.  Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, multiplication is commutative on the integers: so $m\times n = n\times m$, etc.

Comment: @amWhy: you do such a great job of following up! +1

Answer (score 1):

The prime factorization for 1000 is 2*2*2*5*5*5.  So you have three groups you're trying to find.

Comment: You're just missing another 2 in your prime factorization.  So it looks like you're probably doing everything else correctly in finding the 3 groups of numbers, etc.

Comment: I corrected my error, but I don't get 10 with three 2s or with three 5s, so I still don't get it.

Comment: Combine the groups: 2*2*2*5*5*5 = 2*5 * 2*5 * 2*5 if you reorder them, so it becomes 10*10*10, just rearrange the prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

What you're missing is there are indeed 3 factors of 2 in 1000.  Remember, when you multiply a number by 10, you add a 0 to the end of it, so it should be easy to see that

$$1000=10\times10\times10$$

Comment: I corrected my error, but I don't get 10 from three 2s.  I realize it's easy to memorize the cube root of a number like 1000.  That was just an example.  The question was how do I use prime factorization to get a cube root?

Comment: @Ghodmode It looks like amWhy has that part covered.